# Bare Metal X86 assembly using Qemu

Tags: c, assembly, qemu, linker-scripts, x86-emulation

Could you help me understand the bootflow while using Qemu to load bins ? If we consider a simple program like writing ascii to VGA memory, where is bin loaded to when we call

```
qemu-system-i386 -drive 'file=my_image.bin,format=raw' -serial mon:stdio -smp 2
```

As per my understanding, the bios on finding a valid boot sector having the magic pattern 0xAA55, loads this sector to 0x7c00. Does Qemu actually copy the bin into this boot-sector of HDA?

I have seen in many tutorials that a linker script configured with 0x7c00 as the load address  is used for generating the elf. However this elf is converted to a bin and passed to qemu. So, is the load address of 0x7c00 really needed ? Can it be any other value in the linker script ?

Comment: It's not really copied, you specified your file as the content of hda. Yes, the load address is physical 0x7c00 which may be 0:0x7c00 or 0x7c0:0. You should ensure that your linker script and runtime addresses match.

Comment: Hi Jester, could you correct me if I'm wrong. The image that we pass onto qemu should not be having any relocation info right ? So is there really a concept of load address ?

Comment: Especially since it does not have relocations, any memory references in it should match where it is actually executing.

Comment: Wouldn't an elf generated by linker script with say load address 0x1000 and load address 0x7c00 generate the same bin via objcopy ? The relative offsets should be same right ? The assumption here is that we have the data and code everything as a single text section

Comment: @RohitMat Data references generally use absolute addressing, so relative addresses won't necessarily cut it.

Comment: Thanks @fuz. That makes sense

Comment: I think the branches which use absolute address would also get messed up. Now it makes total sense